# jQuery Autocomplete not displaying all matches

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've come upon a very frustrating bug in my jquery autocomplete code. I'm working on a book catalogue for a small library project. The autocomplete is used to aid the user in searching by subject tag or by title.

Here's the code (currently being executed on `$(document).ready();`)

```
var autoData = [];
$.get('/search_bar', function(data){ 
    autoData = $.makeArray(data);
    console.log(autoData);
    });

    $("#search").autocomplete({
      source: function(req, responseFn){
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("(?:^| )" + re, "gi");
        var a = $.grep(autoData, function(item, index){
          return matcher.test(item);
        });
        responseFn(a); 
      },
      minLength: 2
});
```

To focus in on the problem, I've limited the response from the server to a set of 3 titles which should all be returned by starting to type "pag...."

```
console.log(autoData) => ["Pages africaines 1", "Pages africaines 2", "Pages africaines 3"]
```

However, jQuery autocomplete only suggests "Pages africaines 1" and "Page africaines 3", not (as I'd expect) "Page africaines 2" as well, unless you type out the entire title "Pages africaines 2" (at which point it appears as the only suggestion, as one would expect).

I've tested the RegExp/$.grep on the array above, and it seems to work fine:

```
autoData = ["Pages africaines 1", "Pages africaines 2", "Pages africaines 3"]

$.grep(autoData, function(item, index){ return RegExp("(?:^| )pages", "gi") })
=> ["Pages africaines 1", "Pages africaines 2", "Pages africaines 3"]
```

Any insight? The `$.get()` receives a json-encoded response from my rails backend, e.g.:

```
def search_bar
    output = Book.search('pages').map{|bt| bt.title }
    render :json => output.to_json
end
```

(where i've limited the autocomplete to the above example to debug). However, in the Chrome javascript console, autoData is definitely an array object as expected.

Thanks in advance!

(Note: The reason i'm using the above RegExp with "(?:^| )" instead of a word-boundary match like "\b" is because there are often unicode/accented characters in the titles, which seems to break with a "\b" match.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
var matcher = new RegExp("(?:^| )" + re, "gi");
var a = $.grep(autoData, function(item, index){
  return matcher.test(item);
});
```

With:

```
var a = $.grep(autoData, function(item, index){
  var matcher = new RegExp("(?:^| )" + re, "gi");
  return matcher.test(item);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I never would've caught/suspected that. Any hints on why it only got tripped up occasionally? (I only noticed the problem as I embarrassingly tried to demo this feature to the people I'm building the app for.)

Answer (score 1):

The global flag makes the engine remember where to search - each successive `.test` call does not necessarily return the same value when called with the same arguments, because it will start matching after the last index.

A more trivial example:

```
var regexp = /./g;
regexp.test("a"); // true  - nothing special, starting at index 0 to match
regexp.test("a"); // false - starting at index 1, where no character is apparent
regexp.test("a"); // true  - reset; same scenario as test #1 again
```

The simplest thing to do is removing the `g` flag: http://jsfiddle.net/gQjh6/.